# How can I use regex to replace a string on multiple lines, but stop when a specific word is reached?

Tags: regex, notepad++

For example:

```
Hello, my name is Bob
Hello, my name is Mary
Hello, my name is Steve
END
```

How can I replace "Hello, my name is ", but stop at the word END?

Comment: What language/program are you using?

Comment: There are 3 `Hello, my name is` in your sample. Can you give details on what the output is to be after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead to make sure `END` is followed after your pattern using this regex:

```
Hello, my name is(?=[\s\S]*?\bEND\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/5)